# Parsing a Matroska (webm) file , random access streaming

Tags: parsing, webm, matroska

I'm intrested in parsing/streaming an encoded webm file, with random access (seek) get_frame functionality.

I've read the  [matroska specs](http://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/index.html) and I think the Cues section is the way to do that, but I have not found any example on how to do that.

Can anyone point me to an example for seeking/finding frames in a Matroska/webm file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the understanding that each Matroska cluster correlates  to a single keyframe.
The Cues hold the exact position (aka "cluster position") of the first frame in that cluster
 (not necessarily a key frame).
so get_frame/seek is done by decoding the cluster until reaching that frame.